# avahi-daemon enabled but cannot resolve DNS

Tags: google-chrome, dns, android, avahi

I have changed the hostname in `avahi-daemon.conf` file in `/etc/avahi` so as that the `host-name=osmc` and it's uncommented. When I do a `sudo systemctl status avahi-daemon -l` I get the following;

```
● avahi-daemon.service - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.service; enabled)
Active: active (running) since Fri 2016-03-18 23:21:31 GMT; 9h ago
Main PID: 1298 (avahi-daemon)
Status: "avahi-daemon 0.6.31 starting up."
CGroup: /system.slice/avahi-daemon.service
       ├─1298 avahi-daemon: running [osmc.local
       └─1300 avahi-daemon: chroot helpe

Mar 18 23:21:31 osmc avahi-daemon[1298]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Mar 18 23:21:31 osmc avahi-daemon[1298]: Network interface enumeration completed.
Mar 18 23:21:31 osmc avahi-daemon[1298]: Registering new address record for 192.168.0.13 on eth0.IPv4.
Mar 18 23:21:31 osmc avahi-daemon[1298]: Registering HINFO record with values 'ARMV7L'/'LINUX'.
Mar 18 23:21:32 osmc avahi-daemon[1298]: Server startup complete. Host name is osmc.local. Local service cookie is 1330739464.
Mar 18 23:21:33 osmc avahi-daemon[1298]: Service "osmc" (/services/udisks.service) successfully established.
Mar 18 23:21:33 osmc avahi-daemon[1298]: Service "osmc" (/services/ssh.service) successfully established.
Mar 18 23:21:33 osmc avahi-daemon[1298]: Service "osmc" (/services/sftp.service) successfully established.
Mar 19 08:58:24 osmc avahi-daemon[1298]: Files changed, reloading.
Mar 19 08:58:52 osmc avahi-daemon[1298]: Files changed, reloading.
```

I can `ping -c 3 osmc.local` and get 0% loss. However when I try to access a service e.g nzbget or transmission via a chrome on my Android device I get DNS could not be resolved. It works fine on my Ubuntu PC and my Chromebook, any ideas?